# Hello World program in Nasm x86-64 prints Hello World continuously

Tags: assembly, nasm

Could you please help me on this code. On execution, the program prints Hello World continuously and does not exit. I want to use this code as shellcode in C program too, hence I have not defined Hello String in data section. Please let me know where is the issue.

```
SECTION .text       ; Code section
    global _start       ; Make label available to linker 

_start:             ; Standard ld entry point

jmp callback    ; Jump to the end to get our current address

dowork:

    pop     rsi     ;
    mov rax,4       ; System call number for write
    mov     rdi,1   ; 1 for stdout
    mov     rdx,12  ; length of Hello World
    syscall         ; Switch to the kernel mode

    mov     rax,1   ;
    xor rdi,rdi     ;
    syscall         ;

callback:
   call dowork        ; Pushes the address of "Hello World" onto the stack
   db 'Hello World',0xA  ; The string we want to print
```

Comment: `mov   rdi,1` will contain some `00` bytes, which won't work for most shellcode use-cases.  You can `push 1` / `pop rdi`, and create the other small constants with `lea` relative to that.   [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132985)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

- You're using the wrong syscall numbers for x86-64 Linux. Thus your `exit()` call fails and instead `dowork` and `callback` end up in a mutual recursion, causing a loop.
- For the correct syscall numbers, see [arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl?v=3.19) in the Linux source code:

`1       common  write                   sys_write
231     common  exit_group              sys_exit_group`

- If you're willing to embrace AT&T x86 assembler syntax and the C preprocessor, you can `#include <sys/syscall.h>` and use e.g. `SYS_write` as the syscall number for `write`. See `hello-att.S` below. This way you can stop worrying about looking up the syscall numbers.

### hello.asm

```
    SECTION .text   ; Code section
    global _start   ; Make label available to linker 

_start:             ; Standard ld entry point    
    jmp callback    ; Jump to the end to get our current address

dowork: 
    pop     rsi     ;
    mov rax,1       ; System call number for write
    mov     rdi,1   ; 1 for stdout
    mov     rdx,12  ; length of Hello World
    syscall         ; Switch to the kernel mode

    mov   rax,231   ; exit_group(0)
    xor rdi,rdi     ;
    syscall         ;

callback:
    call dowork     ; Pushes the address of "Hello World" onto the stack
    db 'Hello World',0xA  ; The string we want to print
```

### hello-att.S

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

    .global _start
_start:
    jmp callback
dowork:
    /* write(1, "Hello World\n", 12) */
    pop %rsi /* "Hello World\n" */
    mov $SYS_write, %rax
    mov $1, %rdi
    mov $12, %rdx
    syscall

    /* exit_group(0) */
    mov $SYS_exit_group, %rax
    xor %rdi, %rdi
    syscall

callback:
    call dowork
    .ascii "Hello World\n"
```

Knowing AT&T x86 assembler syntax makes reading Linux kernel and glibc source a lot easier ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot scottt for the answer. Now my code works. You have been really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Obviously after the last `syscall` you must exit, return or jump somewhere else, otherwise you have an endless loop and it will crash the stack after some time.

```
mov     rax,1   ;   sys_write
xor rdi,rdi     ;
syscall         ;
```

Either that, or you must use a different syscall because here you do a `sys_write` operation. Maybe you wanted `#60`?